# AdvTree select all nodes programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetbar

I am trying to select all nodes on Ctrl + A on an AdvTree.
it is set to allow multiselect.

I have the event PreviewKeyDown to check ctrl, and A are pressed.

I tried this:

```
For Each nd As Node In tvComputers.Nodes
    nd.SetSelectedCell(nd.Cells(0), Nothing)
Next
```

but its only selecting the last item in the tree, it doesnt seem to add to the selected list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind if found it, but thought ill put up for others to see as i couldn't find anywhere

```
 For Each nd As Node In tvComputers.Nodes
     tvComputers.SelectedNodes.Add(nd)
 Next
```